# Get 50 employees data from each department list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

This is my code

```
public class ViewModel 
{
    public List<Department> Departments{ get; set; }
}
public class Department
{
    public Department();

    public List<Employee> Employees{ get; set; }
}
public void post(ViewModel response)
{
    ViewModel   viewModel= new ViewModel
    {               
      Departments= new List<Department>(){ 
        new Department{ Employees= response.Departments[0].Employees.Take(50).ToList() } }
    };          
}
```

in the above code got 50 employees data from first department, but i want get each department employees data

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ViewModel viewModel= new ViewModel
{               
    Departments = response.Departments.Select(x => 
    { 
        x.Employees = x.Employees.Take(50).ToList(); 
        return x;
    })
    .ToList()
};
```

See working [filddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/m67Lb5)

Comment: Thank You , now i got output

Answer (score 0):

I guess you just need Projection, something like this:-

```
ViewModel viewModel= new ViewModel { 
       Departments = List<response.Select(x => 
                   new Department { Employees = x.Employees.Take(50) }).ToList();
      };
```